# How to scrape when data tables do not show in page source

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I would like to scrape **all** running times (not just the first 10 results) from the data tables on https://www.ijsselsteinloop.nl/uitslagen-2019. However, the data that shows on the webpage does not show in de page source. Under every data table, there's a hyperlink ("hier"). These link to the full data table pages. But those links are also not in the page source.

Any suggestions or code snippets how to scrape this data (with Python and BeautifulSoup or Scrapy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same endpoint the page uses for that content. You can find this in the network tab of the browser.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://www.ijsselsteinloop.nl/uitslag/2019/index.html')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
links = ['https://www.ijsselsteinloop.nl/uitslag/2019/' + item['href'] for item in soup.select('[href^=uitslag]')]

for link in links:
    table = pd.read_html(link)[0]
    print(table)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only returns the 10 first rows of every data table. Under every data table, there's a hyperlink ("hier"). These link to the full data table pages. But those links are not in the page source.

Comment: Thnx, works like a charm!! The LXML parser was my "missing puzzle piece".

Answer (score 0):

You could use BeautifulSoup. First :

```
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")
```

And then use function find.All( to get every tr). And then use for loop , and type
again find('td') to get every row